# A House Divided?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I notice that one moderator has locked a question (from an ongoing contest), and another moderator has unlocked it and edited out part of the notice posted by the first moderator. I don't think this is a good look. Can we encourage the moderators to come to at least an interim agreement as to what to do when they have disagreements about matters that affect all of us, in particular (but not limited to) disagreements about whether to lock certain types of question?

Comment: I noted a recent contest thread which was deleted by one, and undeleted by another. I am aware of several occurrences like these in past as well (e.g. suspensions/de-suspensions, deletion/undeletion of general thread). It saddens to say, but the names involved are almost always the same.

Comment: Two households, both alike in dignity / Should not cross swords, e'en if they disagree

Comment: @Yemon: This is meta.math.SE, not meta.fairVerona.SE :-P

Comment: This is actually warfareandwarcraft.stackexchange

Comment: I think that the problem goes beyond contest questions and should be broadly discussed. There are strong differences between the views of moderators on important matters and there were even cases of expressed animosity between them.

Comment: @Michael It is a *good* thing that the moderators do not always agree on contentious matters since that means that they may be diverse enough to represent the concerns of *all* members of the community, whether they be in academia or not, pure or applied, teacher or student, professional or hobbyist, etc.

Comment: @Bill It might be good that their private opinions differ, but they should follow the same policies. I don't see an advantage of inconsistent policy.

Comment: @Michael There is no "inconsistent policy" because there is no policy on matters where the community has widely varying opinions (e.g. homework, contests, etc). On such matters, the best that the moderators can do is attempt to *mediate* and keep the peace.

Comment: @Bill I don't think there is even consent on whom to suspend. The B-incident comes to mind.

Comment: @Michael Only very, very rarely have there been such differences of opinion, and they involved topics where either there was no clear community consensus, or where community views were largely unknown due to no significant prior meta diuscussions on such topics. Except for these isolated incidents, the site is running fairly smoothly, esp. compared to earlier times where there were many heated arguments on main regarding contentious matters such as homework questions. The recent matters on contest questions are only sparks compared to these earlier flames.

Comment: @Bill It is my impression that you are much more tolerant towards relatively new users than at least some other moderators. So is there a clear consent on when to suspend users?

Comment: @Michael One should not attempt to draw general inferences from a single instance, esp. one that was extremely unusual.

Comment: @Bill I agree, which is I why I don't do that. Can you answer my question?

Comment: @Michael I doubt any moderator could tell you whether or not they are more lenient than another regarding suspensions since no moderator has ever publicly stated how they make such decisions.

Comment: @Bill So how do suspensions usually work? Is there some discussion process involved?

Comment: @Bill, I agree that it is a good thing that the moderators don't always agree on contentious matters. It is, in my opinion, a bad thing if, when contentious matters arise, moderators don't get together to work out a policy that all moderators are then expected to follow. That's what I expect of leadership, and I'm hoping people will suggest protocols to diminish the probability of future failures of leadership.

Comment: I do not perceive this incident as a failure of leadership;it is much better to call it "an attempt to explore and evaluate new territory".

Comment: @BillDubuque Why did you unlock the contest question that Gerry is referring to?

Comment: @Benjalim  Please see the recent related threads for much discussion. Why did you not also ask why they were locked in the first place?

Comment: @zyx: I don't think the [contests] tag fits here. My impression is that Gerry is talking about a bigger problem here.

Comment: @Asaf, I added because of Noah's answer, which explains his proposal made in the other question.  I think the case is made slightly better here than there. The comments discussion underneath is short and readable, not like the other mess, and it has some points not covered in the other (contests) places.  The whole set of parallel discussions was getting harder to follow without one tag to search, and I consider this to be one of the branches.  It does not stop a general discussion of Gerry's question in the abstract.

Comment: @zyx My reading of tags is that each tag restricts what the thread is about. And I don't think that answers should lead to a retagging. I don't want to start a retagging war, but I strongly oppose the addition of the *contests*-tag.

Comment: @Michael, or Asaf, or anyone else who cares: I won't add the tag if you remove it, though I have never seen any sign of a consensus on restrictive/inclusive or question/answer nature of the tags.  There are now 7 different questions on meta derived from the same incident and the same conversation is taking place in all of them at once.  Because of this, someone else created the Contests tag and applied it to some of the postings, and I extended it to the rest.  If you judge the matter differently and remove tags it is between you and the other users, I am done with any tagging on this.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I agree with zyx that the contests tag belongs here.

Comment: @Gerry: Can you solve the dispute whether or not your post aims to discuss the particular context of contests or the general ping-pong which sometimes occurs when the moderators take action on "hot topics"?

Comment: @Asaf, I think the dispute is as to whether one interprets tags as a union or an intersection. I also think that what my post aims to discuss is irrelevant; once I put it out there, it belongs to everyone, and if people want to use it as a pretext for discussing the price of tea in China, so be it. But, for the record, I really wanted to see whether some protocols might evolve to encourage moderators to work out their differences offsite.

Comment: @zyx, Bill: Based on Gerry's comment above I am inclined towards removing the [contests] tag. To avoid tag-wars, if no counter-arguments are presented I will do so tomorrow during the evening (or so). @Gerry: Thank you for the answer!`

Comment: @Asaf, you're welcome. However, as Einstein proved, time is relative. In particular, "evening" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Gerry: Since my residence appear in my profile, it seems reasonable to expect people to have an idea that I mean within the area around 15-18 hours from now. But then again, how can you expect mathematicians to perform acts of natural deduction when one can prey on syntactical ambiguities, or worse: semantic ambiguity (which is a generalization of moral ambiguity, but a lot more fun for mathematicians to attack when writing a reply).

Comment: @Asaf, it's not reasonable to expect people to go look up your profile and then consult some table of world time zones to do the calculation, just to see what evening means to you. Especially since for all we know you could be attending a conference in Buenos Aires. Make life easier on your readers, not harder.

Comment: @Gerry I would tentatively presume that Asaf's tongue was firmly in-cheek in his last comment.

Comment: @Glen, but Asaf didn't use the tongue-in-cheek emoticon!

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but in this particular case it seems as though the post was locked *before* the contest had finished and unlocked *after* the contest had finished. Is that not the case?

Comment: It appears that the contest was to end 1 October, and the unlocking occurred at 2:54 on 1 October. I haven't checked to see what time on 1 October the contest was to end, nor have I checked to see what time zones are relevant. On the face of it, it looks like the contest still had several hours to run when the question was unlocked, but I could be wrong. Anyway, had the contest been finished, I would have expected the person unlocking to have noted that.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with the general sentiment that public moderator disagreements are very bad.  However, in the specific case of requests to temporarily take down questions by people who are clearly cheating, I think that the moderator should delete it and then it should not be undeleted unless moderators come to an agreement.  The reason we have moderators is so that they can respond to important situations quickly, and things should be left in a reversible situation while any discussion takes place.  In this specific situation the reversible situation is locked or deleted, and open is not reversible.  So any needed moderator debate or vote, should happen while the question is deleted.

Comment: I completely agree, but unfortunately the moderators are not in consensus about this.

Comment: Noah, some reversal *has* occurred.  The contest organizers were notified, and put up a notice to contestants on the contest web site (plus whatever email notices they may have sent out; it is an email-based competition).  As with the contest setup itself, they elected not to pursue security, and there are larger security holes and abusible rules in the contest than the possibility of problems being posted here. If they don't care to do more it is not clear to me that mSE should be "holier than the Pope".

Comment: @zyx: I don't understand your comment.  How is complying with reasonable takedown requests going beyond what the person requesting is willing to do?  They can't take down questions here themselves, all they can do is ask a moderator to do so.

Comment: There are actions the organizers had opportunities to perform, and declined (and the takedown request, plus demand for IP addresses, reform of m.SE policies, production of offenders' heads on a plate, etc was from a person *not* organizing the event).  The same for their attitude to the other abusible rules and security holes not related to m.SE.  Thus the organizers' level of concern for security can be calibrated, and it seems to be below that of many commenters here.

Comment: @zyx Can you please tell us what actions the organizers could have taken?  I would like to understand this better.  I appreciated your point, on another thread, about how deleting a post after it was answered would serve only to help the cheater because they would the one most likely to have seen the answer.  For example, when Qiaochu deleted Triangle Geometry Question after it had answers, this would only serve to help the cheater.  Bill was right to undelete it in this case at least.  At least let all involved see solutions if they are posted, not just the one cheating.

Comment: @Graphth The organizers could have made a statement under the question or in MSE meta. They could have alerted all contestants (it is an email contest) to the exact location of the MSE question so as to neutralize the benefit of cheating, and made it clear that they may do the same for any future violations.  They can publish contest results with and without the problem in the MSE question, or with a different weight on that problem. They can write questions that are not easily solved with the software they say not to use. Those are a few that come to mind, I don't think it's a complete list.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/triangle-geometry-question), I was the one who first locked it and then unlocked it. (To clarify on the *man* divided: I vaguely remember there being an appropriate thread on Meta about it, but could not find it using the SE search interface. So I locked the question and started preparing a Meta discussion about that fact. But then lo-and-behold one of the "suggested" questions while composing my Meta discussion turned out to be the Meta discussion I was looking for, so I unlocked the question and added a comment instead.)

The subsequent edits, additional answers, delete/undelete, and closure happened over the weekend when I was not available.

If you meant some other one, feel free to ignore what I just wrote.

Comment: I would never ignore anything you write, but my post was prompted by a different question.

Comment: @WillieWong: I believe Gerry is referring to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204741/counting-and-algebra-problem) which was locked and unlocked by different users.